# Why do low cost airlines allow check in much earlier than «full service» companies?

Tags: software

Ryanair allows check-ins 30 days before departure.
Easyjet, Wizzair follow suit.

- British Airways - 24 hours before departure;
- KLM - 30 hours before
  departure;
- Lufthansa - 23 hours before departure.

Why is that? Could it be that low costers being relatively new have better IT systems?

Comment: Whatever the reason is, I doubt it's the quality of their IT systems.

Comment: I think it’s more likely to be related to their fare structure and the usual absence of flexible fares and overbooking. There’s also no issues with interfaces with other airlines (related to interlining).

Answer (score 5):

"Historically" - meaning about 10-15 years ago, when mobile boarding passes weren't a thing - (european) LCCs required travellers to print the boarding pass before flying or pay extra for check-in at the airport. I can imagine that one reason for them to open online check-in rather early those days, was to allow the average "vacation traveller" to print both boarding passes for outgoing and return flight at home, before heading out on vacation.

Seeing how a lot of people still prefer printed boarding passes - because scanning a code off their smartphone never works, because they are afraid of the battery running low, because handling paper is less of a hassle, because they don't have a smartphone, ... - I think they just never changed that rule, though I have no sources to back up that assumption.

Comment: EasyJet never charged extra for printing boardingpasses but they did allow for early check-in.

Comment: I've had my phone fail on the way to the airport for a flight a few years ago. Battery died, phone bricked. If I'd had to rely on an app on that phone to get on the flight I'd have been incapable of going on my month long vacation... Yay printed tickets and boarding passes

Answer (score 3):

Ryanair actually allows 'check-in' 60 days in advance, but that option is only a way to lure more money from their customers. In reality, 'check-in' more than 24 hours before departure is only possible if you either have a flexi plus ticket (which includes this option) or pay extra to select a seat and does not mean anything more than that you can actually select which seat you will be sitting in.

Without having an expensive flexi plus ticket or paying a premium for seat selection, 'regular' travellers can also with Ryanair not check-in more than 24 hours before the flight and will in that case only be given a random seat. Passengers travelling together will not be assigned seats together unless they pay for the seat selection.